# How to change the buffer unification suffix for non local files?

Tags: tramp

When I open for example the file `syslog.conf` on four different hosts with Tramp the buffer names are

- syslog.conf
- syslog.conf<2>
- syslog.conf<3>
- syslog.conf<4>

When I try to change the buffer with tab completion, this is all I see.  The information which buffer belongs to which host is not visible.

Is it possible to tell Emacs to put the name of the remote host into the buffer name?

I would prefer the following buffer names for non local files.

- syslog.conf@host1
- syslog.conf@host2
- syslog.conf@host3
- syslog.conf@host4

Answer (score 1):

If the files on each host are in a different directory, you might be able to distinguish them by setting the variable `uniquify-buffer-name-style`:

From [(emacs) Uniquify](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html):

> When several buffers visit identically-named files, Emacs must give the buffers distinct names. The default method adds a suffix based on the names of the directories that contain the files. For example, if you visit files /foo/bar/mumble/name and /baz/quux/mumble/name at the same time, their buffers will be named ‘name’ and ‘name’, respectively. Emacs adds as many directory parts as are needed to make a unique name.
>
> You can choose from several different styles for constructing unique buffer names, by customizing the option uniquify-buffer-name-style.

Emacs should do the right thing here. My settings are:

```
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'reverse)
(setq uniquify-separator "/")
(setq uniquify-after-kill-buffer-p t) ; rename after killing uniquified
(setq uniquify-ignore-buffers-re "^\\*")
```

And I get the following buffer names when I open the same file on two hosts:

- local `/etc/hosts` is `hosts`
- remote `/etc/hosts` is `hosts//scp:<username>@<remotehost>`.

Comment: The syslog configuration file is on every host in the same directory.

Comment: I don't have access to a remote host to test this. Can you try setting `uniquify-buffer-name-style` to something and check what happens when you open the same file on multiple hosts? According to this old bug report, the problem has been reported and fixed for some time: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2008-06/msg00091.html

Comment: Actually, I found a file I have access to as an example. See my update.